# Rails find_by_sql using ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select workorders using find_by_sql.  The `where` portion of the sql needs to test against some ruby code:

I tried this:

```
<% Workorder.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM workorders w JOIN empgroups e USING (workgroup_id) WHERE e.employee_id = ?, <%= current_user.employee.id %>").each do |workorder| %>
```

But, it doesn't seem to pre-process the `<%= current_user.employee.id %>`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a little mistake in your syntax. 
`find_by_sql` and `where` expects an array when you are using `?` notation for values.
Also, there is no need to interpolate `current_user.employee.id`
Replace your query with :

```
<% Workorder.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM workorders w JOIN empgroups e USING (workgroup_id) WHERE e.employee_id = ?", current_user.employee.id]).each do |workorder| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is much better to place your selecting code to the controller side, like this:

```
def your_controller_method
  @workorders = Workorder.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM workorders w JOIN empgroups e USING (workgroup_id) WHERE e.employee_id = ?', current_user.employee.id)
end
```

And then you can use it in the view:

```
<% @workorders.each do |workorder| %>
<% end %>
```